# Question 3 from Exercises 2.5.1 from F. Mary Hart - Guide to Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The question tells you that $(a_{3n})^{\infty}_{n=1}$ $(a_{3n+1})^{\infty}_{n=0}$ $(a_{3n+2})^{\infty}_{n=0}$ all converge to a. The question asks you to prove $(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges. 
 Intuitively this makes sense because the sub-sequence of every 3rd term converges. I know how to get from a sequence converging to its sub-sequence converging but I am not sure about the converse.

Comment: Another way to deal with convergence is that a sequence $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$ iff $\{n:x_n\not\in U\}$ is finite whenever $U$ is any open interval that contains $x.$ So let $U$ be any open interval with $a\in U.$ Now for $j\in\{0,1,2\}$ let $U_j=\{3n+j: a_{3n+j}\not\in U\}.$ Then each $U_j$ is finite, and $\{m:a_m\not\in U\}=U_1\cup U_2\cup U_3.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Is the $(x_n)_n$ meant to be just $(x_n)$? If not what does this notation mean? I have not seen this before for convergence. What would I search for to find the proof? Also, if $a \in U$ then how is $U_j = $ {$3n + j : a_{3n+j} \notin U$} not the empty set, or I have I misunderstood? $a \in U$ would mean that all points in the sequence $a$ are in the interval $U$?

Comment: Different people use different notations or abbreviations for a sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$. I often use $(x_n)_n$. R. Engelking,  in his book General Topology, uses $(x_n).$ If a sequence $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$ and if $U$ is an open interval with $x\in U$ then there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $(x- \epsilon , x+ \epsilon )\subset U$ and then there exists $m\in\Bbb N_0$ such that $\forall n>m\,(|x_n-x|< \epsilon ).$ So $\{n:x_n\not\in U\}$ is a subset of the finite set $\{n\in\Bbb N_0: n\le m\}.$

Comment: The "sequence $a$"?? The "$a$" in your Q is one number, not a sequence.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I see thanks for the clarification. So what is a (x in your last comment) in this case? Is it a number related to the sequence?

Comment: $x=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.
2. Apply the definition of a sequence converging to $a$ for each subsequence:

   - There is a positive integer $N_1$ so that $|a_{3n}-a|<\varepsilon$ whenever $n \geq N_1$.
   - There is a positive integer $N_2$ so that $|a_{3n+1}-a|<\varepsilon$ whenever $n \geq N_2$.
   - There is a positive integer $N_3$ so that $|a_{3n+2}-a|<\varepsilon$ whenever $n \geq N_3$.
3. Find a formula for a positive integer $N$ that involves the positive integers in step 2 so that the desired conclusion will follow:

$$|a_k-a|<\varepsilon \text{ whenever } k \geq N$$

---

**[Extra Hint]**  In determining a formula for $N$, consider restating what we obtain from each of the three hypotheses in step 2 as done for the first of the three below:

In other words, if for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we set $k_n=3n,$ then $|a_{k_n}-a|<\varepsilon$ whenever $k_n \geq k_1(N_1)=3N_1.$

Also keep in mind that every positive integer $k$ will be equal to the *index*  $k_n$ of some *term*  $a_{k_n}$ in either one of the three subsequences.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141489/discussion-on-answer-by-m-a-pelto-question-3-from-exercises-2-5-1-from-f-mary-h).